# How can I include null values in BETWEEN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my query's `where` clause I have the condition:

```
User.DateOfBirth BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

Where `@startDate` and `@endDate` are nullable. If  `@startDate` is null, I want all values less than or equal to `@endDate`; if `@endDate` is null, I want all values greater than or equal to `@startDate`; if both are null I want all values.

My failed attempt - returns 0 results

```
((( User.DateOfBirth > @startDate) OR (@startDate Is null)) AND  (( User.DateOfBirth < @endDate) OR (@endDate is null)) )
```

(Editor's note: `BETWEEN` includes the end points (less/greater than *or equal*), but the description for the null cases didn't. I've assumed this is an oversight.

Comment: What is lesser than null?

Comment: You do not to apply the `@startdate` filter if it is null? The same for `@enddate`?

Comment: I assume you mean "if `@startDAte` is null I want all values less than `@endDAte`" (rather than less than `@startDAte` which is null"?

Comment: Do you mean, that if `@startDate` is null, it should filter your data? The same if `@endDate` is null?

Comment: @Richard Exactly that i meant. Corrected the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
[User].DateOfBirth BETWEEN ISNULL(@startDate,[User].DateOfBirth) AND ISNULL(@endDate,[User].DateOfBirth)
```

Comment: this also returning 0 result set

Comment: check whether @startDate is empty

Comment: @subin jacob. can you say sample data and sample parameter.

Comment: Being foolish I was, Sorry. I passed empty string ie '' to the param and sql didn't take it as null.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches spring to mind:

#### Tread the four cases separately and then OR them together:

1. start and end are null: any date matches,
2. start is null, so need DoB <= end
3. send is null, so need DoB >= start
4. neither is null, so need between

This will lead to a long expression.

#### Use [`IsNull`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24881013/67392):

As shown by mehdi lotfi in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24881013/67392).

Comment: What would be the reason(s) to avoid the 4 cases approach, apart from being long?

Comment: Being foolish I was, Sorry. I passed empty string ie '' to the param and sql didn't take it as null.

Comment: @shree.pat18: As shown in other answers: the expression gets very long. On its own not too pad, but if there are many queries, and include other non-trivial conditions things will rapidly get very hard to maintain (note the answers that giving the SQL code are accumulating edits – albeit many merged by the "edits within 5 min" rule of [SO]). The `IsNull` approach is much clearer.

Comment: @SubinJacob I think that comment applies to a different answer?

Comment: Yes, @mehdi lotfi . I posted here to notify you. Thank u

Comment: What will a failed cast return ? For example CAST (2 as datetime)

Comment: @SubinJacob I don't know: so I'll give it a try (since I cannot immediately see how invalid conversions are treated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)). EDIT: interesting result (as is casting `'2'`): why not try it yourself?

Comment: ya I tried. When it is an integer it added that number of days to the 1900 january 1. If not an integer , it resulted in error

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a nullable datetime type you could use

```
User.DateOfBirth BETWEEN isnull(@startDAte, CAST('1753-01-01' AS datetime)) AND isnull(@endDAte, CAST('9999-12-31' AS datetime))
```

for datetime2 use

```
User.DateOfBirth BETWEEN isnull(@startDAte, CAST('0001-01-01' AS datetime2)) AND isnull(@endDAte, CAST('9999-12-31' AS datetime2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from yourtable
where 
(@startdate is null and @enddate is null)
or
(@startdate is null and @enddate is not null and User.DateOfBirth <= @enddate)
or
(@startdate is not null and @enddate is null and User.DateOfBirth >= @startdate)
or
(@startdate is not null and @enddate is not null and User.DateOfBirth BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```

This addresses all possible cases:

- Both parameters are null - return all results
- Non null end date only - return all results where DOB <= end date
- Non null start date only - return all results where DOB >= start date
- Both parameters are non null - return all results where DOB is between start and end dates

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE

((User.DateOfBirth BETWEEN @startDAte AND @endDAte) AND @startDAte is not null AND @endDAte is not null)
OR
((User.DateOfBirth =< @endDAte) AND @startDAte is null AND @endDAte is not null)
OR 
 ((User.DateOfBirth >= @startDAte) AND @startDAte is not null AND @endDAte is  null)
OR 
(1=1 AND @startDAte is null AND  @endDAte is  null)
```